# Set Animation for a group of objects in Android

Tags: java, android, animation, translate-animation

I have several `TextView` objects that I need to animate with the **same** `Animation`.

The way I'm doing it looks wrong, since I can only set `Animation` to each object at time

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    Animation hideLeftBar, showLeftBar;

    hideLeftBar = new TranslateAnimation(195, 0, 0, 0);
    hideLeftBar.setDuration(1000);
    hideLeftBar.setFillAfter(true);

    showLeftBar = new TranslateAnimation(0, 195, 0, 0);
    showLeftBar.setDuration(1000);
    showLeftBar.setFillAfter(true);

    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btGMG:

        if(img_GMG.getAlpha() == (float) 0.3)
        {
            img_GMG.setAlpha((float) 1);
            imgLeftBar.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtRS.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtST.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtTR.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtI1.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtI2.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtI3.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtP1.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtP2.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtP3.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtS1.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtS2.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtS3.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtFP1.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtFP2.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            txtFP3.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            textIndutive.startAnimation(showLeftBar);
            textCapacitive.startAnimation(showLeftBar);


        }
        else
        {
            img_GMG.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
            imgLeftBar.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtRS.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtST.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtTR.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtI1.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtI2.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtI3.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtP1.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtP2.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtP3.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtS1.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtS2.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtS3.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtFP1.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtFP2.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            txtFP3.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            textIndutive.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
            textCapacitive.startAnimation(hideLeftBar);
        }


        break;
    }

}
```

How can I reduce this? Should I do it *programatically* or using `XML` resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an [AnimatorSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html). It has a `playTogether()` [function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#playTogether(java.util.Collection%3Candroid.animation.Animator%3E)) that will play all your animations at the same time. See a good example [here](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1404).

Answer (score 1):

It should implements programmatically. You can do this with ListView if all of your elements show same as each other. With ListView you can do more with your elements so easily.
[List View | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

But if you want change this code rapidly you can use List of TextViews and use it easily:

```
List<TextView> textViews = null;

public void onCreate(View v) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textViews.add(findViewById(R.id.txtRS));
    textViews.add(findViewById(R.id.txtST));
    //Initialize other textViews here.
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    for (int i = 0; i < textViews.size(); i++) {
        textViews.get(i).startAnimation(showLeftBar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `ListView` is not a suitable solution because some values displayed at some `TextView`'s will change all the time.

Comment: If in your ListView use a Holder and call notifyDataSetChanged(); you can change your view dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run multiple animations in parallel you could use the View's ViewPropertyAnimator like this:

`for (int i = 0; i < parentView.getChildCount(); i++) {
     View childView = parentView.getChildAt(i);
     childView.animate().translationX(DELTA_X).setDuration(DURATION_ANIM);
}`

and for the other animation you could use .translationY()